# Wordpress WooCommerce Shop page not behaving

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have had a local version of a custom theme of a website I am working on running absolutely fine. Now since migrating it to webspace I am having some issues with the archive-product.php page within WooCommerce.

There is mean to be a banner along the top of the page which shows a featured product and pulls it from the featured product category if ticked when creating a new product. For some strange reason now it isn't displaying anything at all - I have taken a couple of screen snaps to show you the issue - In the screenshot that says 'Hi' I manually input that to see if it is even doing anything.

[image: Live Version]

[image: Local version]

So as you can see it isn't clearing the div that it sits in either.

Here is the code for the section which is from the archive-product.php page.

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //maximum execution time error
    $args = array(
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'meta_value'     => 'yes',
       'posts_per_page' => 1,
       'product_cat'    => 'featured'
    );
    $product_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <div class="shopBanner">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item" id="id1">
                    <div class="section group">
                    <h1>Hi</h1>
                        <?php while ( $product_query->have_posts() ) : $product_query->the_post(); global $product; ?>
                              <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                              <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                              <h2 style="margin-top:-20px; color: #fff;">
                              <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,120); ?> [...]
                              dfdfsdf
                              </h2>
                              </div>

                        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                            <span class="icon lush-comments" id="heroIcon"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Link button to featured product -->






    <div class="section1" id="section1">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="mainbtn" style="float: left; margin-top: -82px;">View product</button></a><?php endwhile; ?>
                <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_2_of_3">
              Take a look of our range of publications. Selected publications can be purchased via a download also.fnksldfksdjfsdfklasdjfklsdajfkldsjflkdsjfl
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                <div style="float:right;">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="social" style="background-image:url(img/twitterIcon.png);"></button></a>
                        <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="social" style="background-image:url(img/facebookIcon.png);"></button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am really baffled to what I maybe missing? All the product categories are showing as expected and can add products to them but it is this part that is failing?

Comment: The images are probably missing, try checking for broken image links or local urls

Comment: @Anigel It sure isn't broken images as that is a background color and the the image you see there is a font - which is loading correctly on all the other pages apart from this one.

Comment: Ah ok where you said it is meant to be a banner it seemed that it should be an image. my bad

Comment: @Anigel This is a very strange situation I am in here. I cannot understand why it is failing this section only when loaded up to the web?

Comment: Is this the complete code from the archive-products.php? I think there should be more.

Comment: I believe you're missing a 'meta_key=keyname' in your query, which is required when using meta_value...